# Why python logging is treated as errors in azure dev ops pipeline

Tags: python, logging, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have a problem. In my project I'm using python logging, to describe every single step of my program. Code is simple:

```
log = logging.getLogger()
logging.basicConfig(
    handlers=[
        logging.FileHandler("./logs/{:%d-%m-%Y}/".format(datetime.now())+"{:%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S}.log".format(datetime.now()), 'w', 'utf-8'),
        logging.StreamHandler()
    ],
    level=logging.INFO,
    format='[%(asctime)s] %(levelname)s - %(message)s',
    datefmt='%H:%M:%S'
)
```

I don't know why, but pipeline in Azure Dev Ops automaticly treats every log as error, no matter that log is type of INFO or ERROR:

[image]

Same thing is in console output, everything is in red.
How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

That is a default case in Azure DevOps actually to consider python logging as **Warning** or **Error**. To make the logging to use perfect in azure DevOps follow the steps below.

[image]

**Set Loggin Level:**

```
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger('azure.mgmt.resource')

# Set the desired logging level
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
```

**Use General Namespaces:**

```
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger('azure.storage')
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

logger = logging.getLogger('azure')
logger.setLevel(logging.ERROR)

print(f"Logger enabled for ERROR={logger.isEnabledFor(logging.ERROR)}, " \
    f"WARNING={logger.isEnabledFor(logging.WARNING)}, " \
    f"INFO={logger.isEnabledFor(logging.INFO)}, " \
    f"DEBUG={logger.isEnabledFor(logging.DEBUG)}")
```

This is the link of [standard logging libraries](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#levels).

Check out the documentation on official procedure to handle the [logging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/python/sdk/azure-sdk-logging)